# Realm, network operations, subscribing and observing on different threads with RxJava

Tags: rx-java, realm-list, realm

I need to :

- Fetch some data from an API on a background thread
- Display the data on the UI
- Save to Realm.

  ```
  fetchItemsFromServer().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
          .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(new Action1<ItemList>() {
      @Override
      public void call(ItemList items) {

          displayItems(items);

          try {
              realm.beginTransaction();
              realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(itemList);
              realm.commitTransaction();
              Logger.v("Realm ", "Copied list object to realm");
          } catch (Exception e) {
              Logger.e("Realm Something went wrong ", e);
              realm.cancelTransaction();
          }

      }
  }
  ```

This throws an error : ***realm accessed from incorrect thread***

I have 4 tabs fetching different messages at the same time.

fetchItemsFromServer() is an intensive call and confining this call to one thread is not good. I need this flexibility.

Has anyone found any workarounds using realm this way?

Most examples e.g tend to be focused on fetching from Realm vs working with network operations:

Example below:

Rxjava - https://realm.io/news/realm-java-0.87.0/

Using realm with RxJava - https://realm.io/news/using-realm-with-rxjava/ (previous solution but performance drawbacks)

My Realm is provided by a database module through dependency injection (Dagger 2)

```
@Module
public class DatabaseModule {

    public static final String REALM_FILE_NAME = "Realm name";

    @Provides
    Realm providesRealmInstance(Context context) {
    return Realm.getInstance(
            new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context)
                    .name(REALM_FILE_NAME)
                    .build());
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting your Realm instance from in the subscriber? The subscriber is doing the save on the UI thread, so if your Realm instance was created there as well it should work.

Comment: @ChristianMelchior my realm is injected via dependency injection. once I remove subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) for the API call, everything works fine.

Comment: Removing `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` should have no effect on your subscriber as you `observeOn` the main thread. Is your `fetchItemsFromServer()` somehow using Realm?

Comment: @ChristianMelchior no it calls a request which gets the items back as Json, uses Gson to parse into a realm object, ItemList

Comment: Then my best idea is that Dagger is somehow serving you a cached version from another thread. Note that if you configure your Realm as in the example, then you could avoid Dagger by using `setDefaultConfiguration` in your `Application` class and use `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` to create a instance.

Comment: When and where do you inject the Realm instance btw?

Comment: @ChristianMelchior my app component is built in my application class and then can be injected in activities, fragments etc, do you mind if we move this to a chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100762/discussion-between-christian-melchior-and-androidenthusiast).

Answer (score 4):

Instead of saving data on the UI thread I would do it on the background instead using the following pattern:

```
fetchItemsFromServer()
    .doOnNext(new Action1<ItemList>() {
        @Override
        public ItemList call(ItemList list) {
            // Save data on the background thread
            Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
            realm.beginTransaction();
            realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(list);
            realm.commitTransaction();
            realm.close();
        }
    })
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  .subscribe(new Action1<ItemList>() {
    @Override
    public void call(ItemList items) {
        displayItems(items);
    }
}
```

Comment: That means that you probably are getting the exception from somewhere else. This code snippet is guaranteed to only use the Realm instance on 1 thread.

Comment: I spent more time looking into this, you are right. I was getting the exception from somewhere else which was accessing the realm from the UI.