# Using RxJava with Schedulers to update Realm

Tags: realm, rx-java

Im trying to "rxify" my database layer that is based on Realm..

I have this method:

```
public fun insertOrUpdate(user: user): User {
 return Observable.create<UserAccount> {
            try {
                realm.beginTransaction()
                val result = realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(user)
                realm.commitTransaction()
                it.onNext(result)
                it.onCompleted()
            } catch(e: Exception) {
                it.onError(IllegalDataAccess())
            }
        }
}
```

However, I have that error of using realm objects on a different thread, since I'm using a different Scheduler. Is any to overcome this? (I was able to do this on object retrieval, but not on object inserts)

(I'm using kotlin btw.)

Example of usage:

```
userRepo.insertOrUpdateUser(user)
  .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
  .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
  .subscribe(...)
```

Comment: Well, you'll need a Realm instance on the `io()` scheduler. I'm pretty sure I've seen a solution for this somewhere...

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I would appreciate if you found it!

Comment: This looks like it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34812882/2413303

Comment: The answer @EpicPandaForce pointed to should be correct. Just open the Realm inside the Action and close it again when done. That should satisfy the threading checks.